# Attribute getters in python

Tags: python

I vaguely remember learning about some sort of built-in function that would do the equivalent of

```
f = lambda x: x.attr
```

Am I just imagining this or does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`operator.attrgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)

Answer (score 3):

```
getattr(obj, 'attr')
```

will get the attribute `attr` from `obj`, or raise `AttributeError` if it doesn't exist.  You can also supply a default value:

```
getattr(obj, 'attr', None)
```

in which case the default will be returned instead of raising an exception if the attribute can not be found on the object.